# Pass data from jquery dialogue into mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a website that shows a **jQuery** dialogue with a `TextArea` inside it. It also has a save button, what I'm trying to do is to pass the data from the `TextArea` to MySQL database table.

```
onEdit: function (ev, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    $('#NoteDialog').remove();
    return $('<div id="NoteDialog"></div>').dialog({
        title: "Note Editor",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        height: "300",
        width: "450",
        position: { my: "left bottom", at: "right top", of: elem},

        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var txt = $('textarea', this).sceditor("instance").val();
                //          Put the editied note back into the data area of the element
                //          Very important that this step is included in custom callback implementations
                $elem.data("note", txt);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Delete": function () {
                $elem.trigger("remove");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
            var textarea = $('<textarea id="txt" name="text" style="height:100%; width:100%;">');
            $(this).html(textarea);
            //          Get the note text and put it into the textarea for editing
            textarea.val($elem.data("note"));
            textarea.sceditor({
                resizeEnabled: false,
                style: "jquery.sceditor.min.css",
                toolbar: 'bold,italic,underline,subscript,superscript|left,center,right,justify|orderedlist,bulletlist,link,image',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            });
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("textarea").sceditor("instance").destroy();
        }
    });
```

Comment: so wht is the problem with ur code?

Comment: send data via ajax to server script

Comment: @charlietfl i need to pass the data from the textarea into mysql database when the button 'Save' is clicked,

This textarea I mean  (named 'text')
var textarea = $('<textarea id="txt" name="text" style="height:100%; width:100%;">');

Comment: @SaifHarbia only a server script can communicate with mySql. There are many tutorials on how to do this, look for one that has sample code for same server language you are using

Comment: Welcome to SO @saifharbia. Please take some time to read through http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info to help you get the most out of SO.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you click on the button save, send an AJAX request with your textarea data to a PHP file

   ```
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url:"file.php",
    data: {data : your_text_area_data} ,
    success: function (result) {
         //Write there
         //If your php file sends back info, it's in the variable result 
    }
   });
   ```
2. In your php file `file.php`, get your data back and do the query to your data base:

The data from your textarea can be accessed with : `$_POST['data']` and then do your query :

```
INSERT/UPDATE ...
```

Edit : no need to add a callback as I mentionned in the comment (I'm assuming your code is working as it is), you can add the `$.ajax` when your `SAVE` button is triggered :

```
 "Save": function() {
           var txt = $('textarea', this).sceditor("instance").val();
           //Put the editied note back into the data area of the element
           //Very important that this step is included in custom callback implementations
           $elem.data("note", txt);
           //$.ajax here
           $(this).dialog("close");
    },
```

Comment: OP is using a text editor....GET is not appropriate due to character limits and `your_text_area_data` won't create a request key `data` at server either

Comment: how can i guarantee that this is done when the button 'Save' is clicked ?

Comment: @charlietfl edited my post with your suggestions. @Saif Harbia, you have to put this code in a `.click()` : `$( "#idOfYourSaveButton" ).click(function() {
   //Save button is clicked do your thing
});`

Comment: @Pleasure answer is better but code would go in callback of  `SAVE` button , no need for a new event handler. `dialog` already provides event listener

Comment: @charlietfl  thanks guys, your codes worked but still have a small bugs which i couldn't fix. When I looked at the stored data in mysql database I found that it has stored extra data next to the info inserted in the textarea. this is what i got : <p>kn<span id="sceditor-end-marker" class="scedito ,, any suggestions ?

Comment: You only want the string "kn" ?